# How to remove a random item from a ListBox

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I can't remove a random item from `ListBox`

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
 Dim rnd As New Random
 Dim randomIndex As Integer = rnd.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count)
 ListBox1.Items.Remove(randomIndex)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method takes the actual item to remove, not the index.  To remove by index, use [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim randomIndex As Integer = rnd.Next(0, ListBox1.Items.Count)
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(randomIndex)
```